# WCF communication error

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wcf-binding, wcf-security

We've been encountering a WCF communication error for a couple of days now and I can't figure out what is causing the error. I originally thought that it was an SSL cert issue, but it's not. I also made sure the endpoint was reachable by just entering the URL on the web browser and it is view-able. I also made sure that the default request size is not causing the problem. I'm certain that the requests are less than the default of 30MB.

What other things can prevent this stack trace error?

Client stack trace:

> WCFDirector fetch failed due to communication failure.
>
> Because the form did not load properly it must be closed. ---> OSI.Framework.FrameworkException: WCFDirector fetch failed due to communication failure. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>          at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>          at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:

> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Comment: Looks like IO exception, may need to add threading.. Would hurt to see the code of what we service is trying to do..

Comment: Enable WCF tracing on both sides, and also use a tool like Wireshark to capture network packets. Then see how the connection (SSL/TLS) was closed. Many factors can lead to such, like proxy issues or simply wire issues.

Comment: @LexLi Oddly enough, the requests always fail if it reaches the 5 minute mark. What are the possible timeout settings on the server or the services web.config

Answer (score 0):

Try to set KeepAlive off.
Something like:

```
var client = new MyWcfClient();
var customBinding = new CustomBinding(client.Endpoint.Binding);
var transportElement = customBinding.Elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();

transportElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;

client.Endpoint.Binding = customBinding;
```

Config only version for Rest API and SOAP

```
<services>
  <service name="SecureTransportDemo.Service.GreetingService">
    <endpoint address="Soap"
              binding="customBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="soap-secure-nokeepalive"
              contract="SecureTransportDemo.Service.IGreetingService"
              name="soap-nokeepalive"/>
    <endpoint address="Rest"
              binding="customBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="rest-secure-nokeepalive"
              behaviorConfiguration="web"
              contract="SecureTransportDemo.Service.IGreetingService"
              name="rest-nokeepalive"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="soap-secure-nokeepalive">
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport allowCookies="false" 
                      keepAliveEnabled="false"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="rest-secure-nokeepalive">
      <webMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true" 
                      allowCookies="false" 
                      keepAliveEnabled="false"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
               faultExceptionEnabled="true"
               helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot change the code. The service is working for other clients on different servers. It's something that has to do with how the server was configured.

Comment: These are you client proxy settings, not the service ones. So you can try with one client without disturbing the others.

Comment: added config-only version